# How to convert ASCII or Unicode to cyrillic?

Tags: character-encoding, internationalization, ascii

I am trying to convert ascii code or unicode of the key press to cyrillic. I have used keyboard layout manager for this but it is not converting all the characters to cyrillic.

Is there any other way to convert the character into cyrillic? Or do we need to do anything else in keyboard layout manager?

vishal N

Comment: You'll have to give us a little more information. What operating system are you using? What kind of keyboard do you have, how do you read the characters, what values do you get, what values did you expect?

Answer (score 0):

It depends which cyrillic codepage do you use. cp-1251, cp-866 or koi8-r.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_866
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KOI_character_encodings

All three codepages have one byte per symbol and it is very simple to convert. 
It is simple table translation.